# Ansible Role - Multiple Local RPM's Installation Not Working

Tags: linux, ansible, centos, ansible-2.x

I have an ansible role to install local rpm's, and it's downloaded in the files folder location.
When I execute the ansible-playbook command it says "No Rpm found"

**Role**

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   22 Jun 29 14:12 handlers
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   22 Jun 29 14:12 defaults
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   22 Jun 29 14:12 meta
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   22 Jun 29 14:12 vars
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   39 Jun 29 14:12 tests
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   42 Jun 29 17:57 tasks
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   40 Jun 29 18:57 templates
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4.0K Jul  1 01:12 files
[root@localhost playbook]# ls -lrth <role_name>/files/
total 216M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 830K Jun 14 16:19 <rpm_name>-lib-0.103.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  41K Jun 14 16:19 <rpm_name>-0.103.2-2.el7.noarch.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48K Jun 14 16:19 <rpm_name>-0.103.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 432K Jun 14 16:19 <rpm_name>.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 214M Jun 14 16:19 <rpm_name>-0.103.2-2.el7.noarch.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 119K Jun 14 16:19 <rpm_name>.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 124K Jun 14 16:19 <rpm_name>-0.103.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

**tasks/main.yml**

```
  package:
    name: files/"{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ pkgs }}"
```

Getting the below error message

```
    "msg": "No package matching 'files/\"<rpm_name>-0.103.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm\"' found available, installed or updated", 
    "rc": 126, 
    "results": [
        "No package matching 'files/\"<rpm_name>-0.103.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm\"' found available, installed or updated"
```

Give a suggestion on this plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a package on the target system with an RPM file, it *should be present on the target system* at some path.

So your role should first `copy` the RPMs to some destination on target and then run the install command.

Example `tasks/main.yml`:

```yaml
- copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ pkgs }}"

- yum:
    name: "/tmp/{{ item }}"
    state: "present"
  loop: "{{ pkgs }}"
```